# Dependencies of .class file

Tags: java, class, dependencies

For a `.class` file, I would like to list all classes (fully qualified names) that are referenced, i.e. that are imported or otherwise used in the byte code (excluding undetectable things like reflection).

How could I achieve this through Java or command line?

Comment: Have a look at [jdeps](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDK8/Java+Dependency+Analysis+Tool). It ships with JDK8. Earlier you needed to do this with a tool such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html), I believe.

Comment: jdeps works fine (I've tested it), but to make it usable for all our developers, I need a Java 7 compatible approach. Any more ideas? ASM seems to be complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **jdeps** on command line. It is part of jdk.

```
jdeps -v class-name.class
```

**-v** option is used to get class level dependencies instead of default package level dependencies.